# VBA Sum function returns NAME error with linked cell

Tags: excel, vba

Imagine an Excel map with two worksheets. I have linked a cell to an integer from a second sheet (`=Sheet2!A1`) which looks fine in the program.

Now I use VBA to enter a formula,

```vb
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).Formula2 = "=SUMME(A1:A1)"
```

I have to use `Formula2`, `Formula1` enters a `@` which I don't need (and also results in the error).

Now the `#Name!` error appears, but if I manually hit enter in this cell, the SUM function executes correctly. How can I have it work directly with VBA?